# TensorFlow 4-d Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

Use `tf.zeros` to initialize a 4-d Tensor of zeros with size 10 x 256 x 256 x 3.

```py
images =  # TODO

assert isinstance(images, tf.Tensor), "matrix must be a tf Tensor object"
assert tf.rank(images).numpy() == 4, "matrix must be of rank 4"
assert tf.shape(images).numpy().tolist() == [10, 256, 256, 3], "matrix is incorrect shape"
```

Comment: Please provide more information. It is unclear as to what your question is. In addition, please provide any code that you have tried to give more context to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

```py
images = tf.zeros(shape=[10, 256, 256, 3])
```

This is homework, right?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be from the Intro to Deep Learning lab from MIT. https://colab.research.google.com/github/aamini/introtodeeplearning/blob/master/lab1/Part1_TensorFlow.ipynb#scrollTo=Zv1fTn_Ya_cz